# Map<String, Integer> and Map<Integer ,String> sorting

Tags: java, java-collections-api

I am trying to resolve sorting a map , which contains huge data(1000K). 
Is there any efficient way than this to sorting these maps ?
below is the code snippet.

```
    Map<Integer, String> myMap1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    Map<String,Integer>  myMap2 = new HashMap< String,Integer>();

    List <Entry<Integer,String>> lst1 = new ArrayList<Entry<Integer,String>>(myMap1.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(lst1, new Comparator<Entry<Integer,String>>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry e1, Entry e2)
        {
            return ((String) e1.getValue()).compareTo((String) e2.getValue());
        }}
    );


    List <Entry<String,Integer>> lst2 = new ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>>(myMap2.entrySet());        
    Collections.sort(lst2, new Comparator<Entry<String,Integer>>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry e1, Entry e2)
        {
            return ((Integer) e1.getValue()).compareTo((Integer) e2.getValue());
        }}
    );
```

Comment: Are you getting the data from database?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need to sort so much data in memory?

Comment: And what *exactly* do you mean by "1000K"? 1 million *entries*?

Comment: a) Are these lookup dictionaries where the `myMap2` is the "reverse" of `myMap1`? In other words, do the entries in both maps have the same integer and string pairs? b) Would a sorted list of the strings be enough for your task? This might speed things a little bit.

Comment: @Reimeus that is the requirement :)

Comment: @jon Skeet , yep 1 M entries

Comment: @codehx getting data from database but sorting should be done in memory not at database level.

Comment: @NarayanaSai I don't know who told you this, but if the field is indexed then it will be better to do the sorting in database rather than in the app, unless the sorting algorithm is more complex than a simple data comparison, which is not in this case.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ,  just for sorting do i need to use database connection ?

Comment: If you obtain the data from database, obtain it sorted already. Only sort on app when: 1) the field to sort is not indexed and the database may take lot of time doing the sort by itself, or 2) the sorting algorithm is more complex than a single field comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO a priority queue can also be a good approach:

```
Map<Integer, String> myMap1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
PriorityQueue<Entry<Integer, String>> pq = new PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer,String>>(myMap1.size(), new Comparator<Entry<Integer, String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<Integer, String> arg0, Entry<Integer, String> arg1) {
        return arg0.getValue().compareTo(arg1.getValue());
    }
});
pq.addAll(myMap1.entrySet());
while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(pq.poll());
}
```

Also Google Guava can be a good option as it provides a BiMap implementations which can be inversed, and then just sort on inversed map keys.

```
 Map<Integer, String> myMap1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    // insert values in myMap
    Map<String,Integer>  myMap2 = myMap1.inverse();
    SortedMap<Integer, Character> sortedInversed = new TreeMap<Integer, Character>(myMap2 );
```

Comment: You will be better by using a `TreeMap` rather than `HashMap`. `TreeMap` is already sorted.

Comment: In TreeMap insertion will be O(lg n) where as it would be O(1) in Map. Also IMO `Set` and `Map` do not handle duplicates well.

Comment: *IMO Set and Map do not handle duplicates well* looks like you haven't used them in the right way then, but that's aside of the problem. Also, inserting in the `PriorityQueue` will take time O(lg n), so you have to pay that price in order to sort, regardless of the data structure you choose.

Comment: A map doesn't allow duplicates. And `TreeMap` uses a red black tree, which is a balanced tree so you won't have the `LinkedList` situation as you describe. I really don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry I meant they don't handle duplicates well in case of keys.

Comment: Yes TreeMap uses RedBlackTree but it will have its own associated cost of balancing for insertion/deletion etc.

Comment: And that costs is O(1), so there's no big associated cost on it. In this way, both `TreeMap` and `PriorityQueue` will behave and perform the same, so there's no great improvement by using a different structure to *sort* the data. In fact, I'm starting to think that using a `Map` here is a very bad idea to begin with.

Comment: In that case it seems we can't have values with the same key in `TreeMap` whereas in a priority queue I think we can. That is the only plus point, IMO.